# Defining lines in $\mathbb C^n$

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

I was wondering if there is a usual or natural way to define lines between vectors in the vector space $\mathbb C^n$. I haven't encountered one before.

In the space $\mathbb R^n$, lines are of the form $\{\vec x +t\vec y\ :t\in \mathbb R\}$ for some $\vec x, \vec y \in \mathbb R^n$

And it's natural to identify $\mathbb C^n$ with $\mathbb R^{2n}$, but I am not exactly  sure if this gives a good way to define lines in $\mathbb C^n$.

Could someone please give some insight?

Comment: Do we mean *real* lines or *complex* lines? For the former, it's the same definition you already used. For the latter, you just have $t\in\Bbb C$ instead.

Comment: @TedShifrin My question is a bit vague, but I am wondering how we would define the line between two vectors in $\mathbb C^n$? Also, how would this relate to the process of finding such lines in $\mathbb R^{2n}$, where we can find a "position" vector and a "direction" vector (giving a set of the form I wrote in my original post).

Comment: It's exactly the same. It's just a question of whether you mean (the translate of) a complex $1$-dimensional subspace of $\Bbb C^n$ or (the translate of) a real $1$-dimensional subspace of $\Bbb C^n = \Bbb R^{2n}$.

Comment: @TedShifrin I see, I think that I want complex lines as you describe them. As an example, if I wanted a line joining $\vec x$ and $\vec y$ in $\mathbb C^n$, I could take $\{\vec x + t(\vec y-\vec x) :t\in \mathbb C\}$, correct?

Comment: Yes. Do you have a particular problem or application in mind?

Comment: @TedShifrin No, I just had never seen a definition for basic lines in $\mathbb C^n$ in any linear algebra books I've used. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The natural framework in which we can rigorously define a line between two points is an [affine space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_space#Definition), where the ''addition'' of a point and a vector is defined.  In these spaces a line has equation $X=P+t\vec v$ where $P$ is a given point , $X$ is a point on the line and $\vec v$ is a ''direction vector'' and $t$ is a scalar of the vector space underlying  the affine space.

So, in your question it is essential to specify if the subtended vector space is $\mathbb{C}^n$ over  $\mathbb{C}$ or over  $\mathbb{R}$.

Note that $\mathbb{C}^n$ over $\mathbb{C}$  is a vector space of dimension $n$ , but $\mathbb{C}^n$ over $\mathbb{R}$ has dimension $2n$.